# Android 4.0 - Is it required to implement the soft keyboard when needed?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I'm very new to Java and the Android SDK but I'm almost done with porting one of my iOS apps over to Android. I'm targeting Android 2.2 (minSdkVersion=8) and higher and recently bought a cheapo LG Optimus S with 2.2.1 for $75 to test with. On the AVDs I've set up (2.2 & 2.3.3) and my test device (2.2.1), everything is working as expected: user data input, graphing user results, sharing on facebook and twitter, and uploading data to a mysql database via php. My problem arises when I test my app on AVDs 3.1, 3.2, and 4.0. Simply put, the Soft Keyboard does not pop up at all when I select an EditText box with any of these versions through the AVD. This behavior didn't occur in 2.2, 2.2.1, or 2.3.3.

I've created and deleted at least a dozen AVDs and have set Keyboard support = no, Keyboard lid support = no, and any other related input type to no and the Soft Keyboard still doesn't pop up when I click on an EditText box. After tinkering with 3.2 through the AVD, I was able to set up the Soft Keyboard and use it with my app, so that's no longer a concern. However, I still can't get it to pop up with 4.0. Should I even worry about this? After all, it's just an AVD and not the real thing. Will an actual Android 4.0 device without any type of physical keyboard know when to pop up a Soft Keyboard or do I need to add some keyboard show/hide methods for it (and maybe 3.1/3.2)? I can't buy a cheapo Android 4.0 device yet..

Thanks,
j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you aren't doing anything weird, tapping on an EditView should pop up a keyboard on any device that doesn't have a hardware keyboard so it should work fine on a 4.0 device.

I'd still try to get the AVD working correctly. Pop-up keyboards work fine on my 4.0 AVDs.

Comment: I would like to add the fact (however irrelevant to the question) that the hardware keyboard only over rides when its open

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I finished pulling my hair out and was about to pull my reproductive member off and toss it in the air. When I was creating and deleting those AVDs, I noticed that I had to sometimes re-set the some of the Hardware Properties to no. This normally happened when I added 3-4 properties, set them all to no, and then created the AVD. Once I edit the said AVD, I would see that some of the properties were still set to yes.. This ever happen to you? I'm starting to wonder if it's my Mac environment. The 4.0 AVD I have pops up a lot of Asian font errors that I can't read..

Comment: @Samuel, thanks for the additional info as I was wondering about that too. I do like the way Android uses the Soft Keyboard automatically and adjusts to the EditText correctly. iOS is a different story..

Comment: @7rashcan not a problem, as a developer I notice many different little things when having these phones, that was one I noticed when I had my Droid A855

Comment: I'm not clear on how you resolved the problem. If I understand correctly, in 3.2, the softpad doesn't show because my computer has a keyboard. But when I press enter on the computer keyboard, the onKey listeners do not fire.